# How to share gif file to Facebook, Twitter, Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created .gif file and saved in local path. Gif is playing fine when sharing on gmail. But its not working while sharing on facebook, Twitter and instagram. Its showing the first image of gif.  Below is my sample code

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0].appending("/animated.gif")
    pathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: pathURL!)!
    let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [imageData]    
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    vc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don't believe Instagram supports animated GIF uploads at all, you'd need to turn it into a .mp4. Facebook only supports them as links in the post, not as uploads, so you'd need to upload it somewhere and use the URL (or convert it to a video like with Instagram). Twitter fully supports them, to my knowledge, so we'd need to see an example of a post where it didn't work right.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for your quick response. I agree Instagram not allow you to upload Gif but its not working for facebook and twitter. When we tried to upload gif from android device its working well